# I need help uninstalling PostgreSQL on my Mac running 10.7

Tags: macos, postgresql

I got PostgreSQL from [here.](http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgdownload#osx)

Since I'm on 10.7 OS X, I'm having problems.

I want to uninstall the software I got from enterprisedb.

Any tips?

Comment: I edited your question a bit. Am I right calling it PostgreSQL? Your original post said "postgres". Is this right? Please feel free to rollback if you didn't like the changes I made.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.enterprisedb.com/resources-community/pginst-guide

There is a one-click uninstaller that removes everything except the data director and user account. The default data directory is /Library/PostgreSQL/$VERSION/data, so rm -rf that directory (or wherever you instructed the installer to create it).

To remove your postgres user (assuming it is named 'postgres'), first list your users to verify that the user 'postgres' and group 'postgres' are what you expect: (just a safe check) before deleting anything.

`sudo dscl . -read /Users/postgres`

`sudo dscl . -read /Groups/postgres`

Look for the "real name" field, to ensure that it matches the version of the db you are removing.

Then remove the user and groups:

`sudo dscl . -delete /Users/postgres`

`sudo dscl . -delete /Groups/postgres`

Obviously, be careful when using sudo.

Answer (score 0):

The uninstallation instructions are at the bottom of [the installation guide](http://www.enterprisedb.com/resources-community/pginst-guide) linked from that download page.